# JSF - Se borran mis variables del form al validar

Tags: jsf, glassfish

estoy trabajando JSF con glassfish, cree un login que tiene un registro los datos se guardan para luego volver al index para iniciar sesion pero a la hora de comparar la variables del login con las del registro los datos de registro desaparecen y compara los datos del index con **null** antes ya habia trabajado asi sin problema, he intentado de mil formas arreglar el borrado pero no lo he logrado, esta organizado de la siguiente forma.

**index.xhtml** este es mi login donde se puede acceder al registro

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>PARCIAL1</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <center>
            <h:form>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body{background:dimgray}
                </style>
                <h3>SISTEMA BANCARIO</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cedula</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText value="#{usuario.user}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contraseña</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText value="#{usuario.pass}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p>
                    <h:commandButton value="Iniciar" action="#{usuario.validar()}"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Registrate" action="registro"/>

                </p>                                                                       
            </h:form>
            <span>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{usuario.getCedula()}"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{usuario.getContraseña()}"></h:outputLabel>
            </span>
        </center>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**registro.xhtml** este es la pagina de registro donde se especifican principalemente cedula y contraseña para luego ser comparados en el login.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Answer</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {background: dimgray}
        </style>
        <center>
        <h1>REGISTRATE</h1>
        <h:form>
             <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombre:</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText value="#{usuario.nombre}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Apellido:</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText value="#{usuario.apellido}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cedula:</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText value="#{usuario.cedula}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Edad:</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText value="#{usuario.edad}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Correo:</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText value="#{usuario.correo}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Telefono</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText value="#{usuario.telefono}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contraseña</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText value="#{usuario.contraseña}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 <tr></tr>
                </table>
            <h:commandButton value="Registrarse" action="index"/>
        </h:form>
        <br></br>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{usuario.getCedula()}"></h:outputLabel>
        <a href="index.xhtml">Volver</a>
        </center>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Mi managebean **Usuario.java** donde se guardan los datos del registro y luego son comparados con los datos que el usuario digita en el login usando el metodo **usuario.validar**.

```
package com.test;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Usuario {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String cedula;
    private String edad;
    private String correo;
    private int telefono;
    private String contraseña;
    private String user;
    private String pass;

/*Este es el metodo donde se valida al undir iniciar*/
        public String validar(){

        System.out.println(user+" "+cedula+" "+contraseña+" "+ pass );

       if (user.equalsIgnoreCase(cedula) && pass.equalsIgnoreCase(contraseña)) {
          return "panel.xhtml";
        }
        return "index.xhtml";
    }


    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }



    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }



    public void setEdad(String edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public void setContraseña(String contraseña) {
        this.contraseña = contraseña;
    }





    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }



    public String getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public String getContraseña() {
        return contraseña;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elige sessionscoped o viewscoped en lugar de request. Recuerda que los valores de tipo request están disponibles en una única petición http